# How to convert voxelgrid to pointcloud in open3d python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, point-clouds, open3d

I have a voxel grid datatype coming from carving. Now, I would like to convert this voxel grid into a point cloud. The main reason behind this is that I need to get a mesh out of my voxel grid volume.

Is it possible?

What I found so far is the voxel grid's `get_voxels()` method returning all voxels. Then, I manually create a point cloud out of it, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

I post my manual solution.

```
point_cloud_np = np.asarray([voxel_volume.origin + pt.grid_index*voxel_volume.voxel_size for pt in voxel_volume.get_voxels()])
```